# Storing an array in a session

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, session

So I'm trying to store an array in a session, but instead of making it an array it just counts everything up all the time! I just want the value that is done in the session, so I can check if the number isn't done already! There meight be a smarter way to it, but this will do for now!

```
public function nextNumber($list) {

    $i = rand(1, count($list)-1);

    echo $list[$i];

    if (!in_array($list[$i], Session::get('savedlist'))) {
        Session::put('savedlist', Session::get('savedlist') + $list[$i]);

        var_dump(Session::get('savedlist'));

        return $list[$i];
    }

}
```

And this is my put function

```
public static function put($name, $value) {
     return $_SESSION[$name] = $value;
}

public static function get($name) {
    return $_SESSION[$name];
}
```

Comment: FWIW, that `$i = rand()` business looks suspicious; are you deliberately skipping index 0 of your list?

Comment: FWIW, you should prefer mt_rand. Or array_rand in your case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if I undersood your question correctly, however I think that the put function needs to be updated:

```
public static function put($name, $value) {
    if(empty($_SESSION[$name])){
       // create a new array with the given name
       $_SESSION[$name] = array($value);
    } else {
       // add a new item at the end of the array
       $_SESSION[$name][] = $value;
    }
}
```

adding the two square brackets after `[$name]` will insert `$value` as a new item at the end of `$_SESSION[$name]`. Otherwise it will be only a variable, not an array.

Then change the `nextNumber($list)` function as follows

change this line:

```
Session::put('savedlist', Session::get('savedlist') + $list[$i]);
```

with

```
Session::put('savedlist', $list[$i]);
```

So the new value will be put at the end of the `savedlist` array.

Comment: Yea, that is what I want :D

Comment: mmmh, my session still returns a int instead of an array.. 

Warning: Cannot use a scalar value as an array in C:\Development\list\classes\Session.php on line 13

thats this line: $_SESSION[$name][] = $value;

Answer (score 0):

I can't fully understand what you want to do, but since you accepted @lastYorsh answer, I'll assume you want something like his.

If we assume that `Session::get('savedlist')` can return an array then you can't
add a number to an array with the `+` sign. `Session::get('savedlist') + $list[$i]`

I think @lastYorsh implementation should also have an `if statement` 
for the case that second argument is an array `is_array()`.

Furthermore.

> Warning: Cannot use a scalar value as an array

Try this

```
$_SESSION[$name] = []; // array();
$_SESSION[$name][] = $value;
```

But then

```
if (!in_array($list[$i], Session::get('savedlist'))) {
```

You can't use the `in_array` in associative arrays.

---

That lead us to the conclusion that @lastYorsh answer isn't what you want. 
Leave your `Session` implementations as it is and change this

```
if (!in_array($list[$i], Session::get('savedlist'))) {
        $savedlist = Session::get('savedlist');
        array_push($savedlist, $list[$i]);
        Session::put('savedlist', $savedlist);
```